# Есть ли способ закрасить каждое слово?

Tags: html, css3, text

К примеру есть такая конструкция :

```css
div{
  width:300px;
}
p span{
 background:#cc0000;
 padding:0 10px;
 border-radius:8px;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 color:#cc0000;
}
::selection{
  color:transparent;
  background:transparent;
}
::-webkit-selection{
  color:transparent;
  background:transparent;
}
::-moz-selection{
  color:transparent;
  background:transparent;
}
p{
  line-height:22px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
 <span> Praesent </span><span>sapien</span> <span>massa,</span> <span>convallis</span><span> a pellentesque</span> <span>nec,</span><span> egestas non nisi. </span><span>Vestibulum</span><span> ac diam </span><span>sit amet quam</span> <span>vehicula</span><span> elementum sed</span><span> sit amet dui.</span><span> Praesent sapien</span> <span>massa, convallis</span><span> a </span><span>pellentesque nec,</span><span> egestas non nisi.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Но если каждое слово поместить в тег `<p></p>` без `<span></span>` то лично у меня ни чего не получается , т.е надо каждое слово сделать не видимым как в примере **Выше** но при этом что бы текст был расположен просто в теге `<p></p>`,.Как добиться этого же без вложенных `<span></span>`?

Comment: Вряд ли такое возможно, текстовая нода не имеет форму и параметры отображения на нее не распространяются

Comment: быть может там Shadow DOM?

Comment: как я полагаю, стили остаются те же, только с помощью JS текст разбивается на массив слов, а затем склеивается, но уже с оборачиванием слов в span. А чтобы не портить контент, мне кажется, можно полученный результат поместить в Shadow DOM. Я раньше с ним и сам не работал (не было прецедента), но вопрос интересный, попозже попробую накидать пример )

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons/les2094/demo/index2.html  вот он этот пример

Comment: Ахаха, там все гораздо проще =) Это шрифт такой =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобного результата можно достичь подменой шрифта на [BLOKK](http://blokkfont.com/)

---

**UPD**: А вот и решение с помощью Shadow DOM, о котором я писал в комментариях (было интересно попробовать реализовать):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var target = document.querySelector('p'),
    wordSet = target.textContent.match(/[^\s]+/g),
    shadowHTML = '',
    shadowRoot = target.createShadowRoot();

  wordSet.forEach(function(word) {
    shadowHTML += ` <span>${word}</span> `;
  });
  
  shadowRoot.innerHTML = shadowHTML;
  
  /* Как видим, содержимое элемента не изменилось ;D */
  console.log(target.innerHTML);
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
         -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
p::shadow span {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: transparent;
  background: #cc0000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Praesent <i>sapien massa</i>, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet <b>quam</b> vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
</p>
```

Вот что мне помогло в его достижении:

- [Shadow DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/shadow-dom)
- [Стили и селекторы](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-scoping)

Comment: если скажем не использовать этот шрифт ,то есть варианты ? желательно пример с 10 словами

Comment: @Geyan я же предложил альтернативный вариант при помощи JS. Правда тут надо учитывать, что Shadow DOM прожует не каждый браузер, да и шаблонный строки надо будет поменять на обычные, а то опять же фича новая, не всеми поддерживается.

Comment: Костя - ты можешь мне пояснить кое что ??

Comment: @Geyan http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43848/